# Easy way to draw atomic orbitals and integrate them into ChemFig structures

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I'm looking for a method to draw molecules as skeleton structures via chemfig and include some atomic orbitals (i.e. s, p and d orbitals and some sp-hybrid orbitals too) into them (at positions where chemfig places atomlabels, i.e. at the ends of bonds). I give you an example:

[image]

The shapes needed for the different orbitals essentially boil down to the following

[image]

The right appearence would then be achieved by rotating and scaling these orbitals. This should ideally work with a simple command which tells `chemfig` to insert an orbital of a certain type (i.e. s, p, d, ...) at an atomic position and how this orbital shall be rotated, scaled or colored and which phase it should have. Is this doable? Or is there a package out there which provides such a functionality?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package offers s,p and sp-hybrid orbitals (based on TikZ), d orbitals are missing (for now). These are examples from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\begin{document}

 \setbondoffset{0pt}
 \chemsetup[orbital]{
   overlay ,
   opacity = .75 ,
   p/scale = 1.6 ,
   s/color = blue!50 ,
   s/scale = 1.6
 }
 \chemfig{\orbital{s}-[:-20]{\orbital[scale=2]{p}}{\orbital[half,angle=0]{p}}{\orbital[angle=170,half]{p}}{\orbital[angle=-150,half]{p}}(-[:-150]\orbital{s})-\orbital{s}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}

\begin{document}

 \chemsetup[orbital]{
   overlay,
   p/color = black!70
 }
 \setbondoffset{0pt}
 \chemfig{?\orbital{p}-[,1.3]{\orbital[phase=-]{p}}-[:30,1.1]\orbital{p}-[:150,.9]{\orbital[phase=-]{p}}-[4,1.3]\orbital{p}-[:-150,1.1]{\orbital[phase=-]{p}}?}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That's an awesome package. That mostly solves my problem. There is only one tiny drawback: it includes s, p and sp-hybrid orbitals but no d orbitals. Is there also a solution for that? Or could you include them in a future version of `chemmacros`?

Comment: @Philipp I have that on my TODO list for a while now. Maybe I can put it a bit higher on my list, though.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have skipped the sentence where you alread wrote that there are no d orbitals included in the package. I guess I got distracted by the stunning pictures ;) It's nice to hear that it is already on your TODO list. Until then I will try to get by with ChemDraw when I have to draw something with d orbitals.

Comment: The only real problem is the `d$_z$` orbital. The others could be modelled by using 4 times `\orbital[half]{p}` with appropriate angles and colors...

Comment: I guess it is the torus contained in the $\mathrm{d}_{z^2}$ orbital which makes things complicated. Would it make things easier to build the orbital from two half p orbitals sandwiching an ellipse  between them (like in the pictures contained in my question) or can't this be handled properly when it comes to rotation, scaling etc.?

Comment: @Philipp actually I haven't had time yet to look into it but something like that sounds like the way to go... Maybe I'll find the time this weekend.

Comment: @cgnieder thank you for simplifying the drawing of atomic orbitals. In the example showing the p-orbitals in benzene above, is it possible to scale the image. When I tried to incorporate it in a `tikzpicture` environment and `[scale=0.5]` nothing happened. Am I completely wrong using a `tikzpicture` even though `chemmacros` is based on `pgf-tikz`?

Comment: @Leeser you can scale the orbitals themselves via `\chemsetup[orbital]{scale=<num>}` and the `chemfig` formula via `\setatomsep`. Their reaction to a tikzpicture _should_ be independent... without a MWE it's hard to say.

Comment: @cgnieder Thanks for that, will implement when necessary! The MWE I used is `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
 \chemsetup[orbital]{
   overlay,
   p/color = black!70
 }
 \setbondoffset{0pt}
 \chemfig{?\orbital{p}-[,1.3]{\orbital[phase=-]{p}}-[:30,1.1]\orbital{p}-[:150,.9]{\orbital[phase=-]{p}}-[4,1.3]\orbital{p}-[:-150,1.1]{\orbital[phase=-]{p}}?}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`    ie just added a`\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]` before the `\chemsetup' and an `\end{tikzpicture}` before `\end{document}.

Comment: @Leeser as you've seen yourself this isn't working. Both the chemfig formluae and the orbitals are independent tikzpictures and should be scaled according to their own options...

Comment: [Kundschaft](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/477251/121799) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the dz2 orbital problem, I found a poor's guy solution using tikz (I was not able to let the ball shading brighter, as in the chemmacros. I'm not a latex expert, just gather other people's stuff. Hopefully something better comes out):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

% tikz packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

% chemistry packages
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{all}
\chemsetup[orbital]{
   overlay,
   p/color = black!70
 }

% defining orbitals in boxes to put chemfig inside tikz environment
\newsavebox\UpBox
\sbox\UpBox{\orbital[half,angle=90,scale=3]{p}}
\newsavebox\DownBox
\sbox\DownBox{\orbital[half,angle=270,scale=3]{p}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%back axis
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (-2,0) node[anchor=north west] {};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (0,-2.5) node[anchor=south east] {};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (1.5,1.5) node[anchor=north west] {};


% orbital p (half) down
\draw (0,0) node {\usebox\DownBox};

% drawing simple torus
\fill[ball color=white] (0,0) ellipse (1 and .55);
\begin{scope}
  \clip (0,-.9) ellipse (1 and 1.1);
  \path[draw](0,1.1) ellipse (1 and 1.1);
\end{scope}

% orbital p (half) up
\draw (0,0) node {\usebox\UpBox};

%front axis
\draw[thick,->] (.85,0) -- (2,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw[thick,->] (0,1.4) -- (0,2.5) node[anchor=south east] {$z$};
\draw[thick,->] (-.4,-.4) -- (-1.5,-1.5) node[anchor=north west] {$y$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]