# Drawing atomic orbitals upon a chemfig structure

Tags: chemfig

Is there a way to draw an atomic orbital in a `chemfig` structure? I think you can better understand if you see want I want to get:[image: resonance between different diradical structure: it's worth to note that one radicalic center is sigma, the other pi]

Here is what I've already done. Any improvement would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros,chemnum,modiagram}
    \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
        \makeatletter
        \def\CF@node@content{%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                \printatom\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                {\csname atom@\number\CF@cnt@atomnumber\endcsname}%
                \ensuremath{\CF@node@strut}%
            }
        \makeatother
        \chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}
        %\renewcommand*\printatom[1]{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#1}}}
        \renewcommand*{\printatom}[1]{{\sffamily\cf{#1}}}
        \setdoublesep{0.32500 em}  % 'Bond Spacing'
        \setatomsep{1.78500 em}    % 'Fixed Length'
        \setbondoffset{0.18265 em} % 'Margin Width'
        \newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} % 'Line Width'
        \setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
\setbondoffset{0pt}
 \chemsetup[orbital]{
   overlay ,
   opacity = 0.5 ,
   p/scale = 1.25 ,
   s/color = gray!50 ,
   s/scale = 1.25
 }
 \chemfig{*6(-=(-(-[,.2,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,}\orbital{s}))-=(-[,.4,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,}{\orbital[half,angle=90]{p}})-=-)}
\arrow
\setbondoffset{0pt}
 \chemsetup[orbital]{
   overlay ,
   opacity = 0.5 ,
   p/scale = 1.25 ,
   s/color = gray!50 ,
   s/scale = 1.25
 }
\chemfig{[:-60]*6(-=-(=)-(-[,.0,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,}\orbital{s})-(-[,.4,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,}{\orbital[half,angle=90]{p}})=)}
\arrow
\setbondoffset{0pt}
 \chemsetup[orbital]{
   overlay ,
   opacity = 0.5 ,
   p/scale = 1.25 ,
   s/color = gray!50 ,
   s/scale = 1.25
 }
\chemfig{*6(-=(-\orbital{s})-=-=)}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen [Easy way to draw atomic orbitals and integrate them into ChemFig structures](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60711/5049)?

Comment: Yes, sure. I already knew chemmacros. But what you get using `chemmacros`is a 3d image of the orbital, I wanted to draw a scheme similar to that of the image. Moreover, I didn't find anywhere how insert the electron (the dots) in the orbital.

Comment: `chemmacros`' orbitals are `tikzpictures` internally. You can use the same procedure: define macros that draw the orbitals in the way you want them and then place those macros in place of the atoms like in the post I linked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final result, quite satisfactory:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros,modiagram}
    \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
        \makeatletter
        \def\CF@node@content{%
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                \printatom\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
                {\csname atom@\number\CF@cnt@atomnumber\endcsname}%
                \ensuremath{\CF@node@strut}%
            }
        \makeatother
        \chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}
        \renewcommand*{\printatom}[1]{{\sffamily\cf{#1}}}
        \setdoublesep{0.32500 em} 
        \setatomsep{1.78500 em}    
        \setbondoffset{0.18265 em} 
        \newcommand{\bondwidth}{0.06642 em} 
        \setbondstyle{line width = \bondwidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}\centerline{
\schemestart
\chemsetup[orbital]{
  overlay,
  opacity=.4,
  p/scale=1.5,
  p/half,
  s/scale=1.3
}
\chemname{\chemfig[][scale=0.75]{*6(-=(-(-[,.2,,,draw=none]\Lewis{0.,}\orbital{s}))-=(-[-2,0.001,,,draw=none]{{\orbital{p}}})(-[2,.4,,,draw=none]\lewis{2.,})-=)}}{{\footnotesize A'': \textsigma\ap{1},\textpi\ap{1}}}
\arrow{<->}
\chemsetup[orbital]{
  overlay,
  opacity=.4,
  p/scale=1.5,
  p/half,
  s/scale=1.3
}
\chemname{\chemfig[][scale=0.75]{[:-60]*6(-=-(=)-(-[-2,0.001,,,draw=none]{{\orbital{s}}})(-[0,.1,,,draw=none]\lewis{2.,})-(-[-2,0.001,,,draw=none]{{\orbital{p}}})(-[2,.4,,,draw=none]\lewis{2.,})=)}}{{\footnotesize A'': \textsigma\ap{1},\textpi\ap{1}}}
\arrow{<->}
\chemsetup[orbital]{
  overlay,
  opacity=.4,
  p/scale=1.5,
  p/half,
  s/scale=1.3
}
\chemname{\chemfig[][scale=0.75]{*6(-=(-\orbital{s})-=(-[-2,0.001,,,draw=none]{{\orbital{p}}})(-[2,.6,,,draw=none]\lewis{2.,})(-[2,.4,,,draw=none]\lewis{2.,})-=)}}{{\footnotesize A': \textsigma\ap{2},\textpi\ap{0}}}
\schemestop
}
\end{figure}\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice :) If you move `\chemsetup` outside of the scheme you won't have to repeat it. BTW `\centerline{}` is a plain TeX command and shouldn't be used in LaTeX. Since you're in a `figure` a simple `\centering` would suffice. Another BTW: `\chemsetup[chemformula]{format=\sffamily}` seems useless since you're using `mhchem`'s `\cf` anyway.